# Check for availabe services

Tags: qt

I'm writting a server app in Qt. and have Loader class that checks for available services. So, in order to launch server successful I need to check through `Loader` e.g. programmatically, whether MySQL service is functioning or not. I've found out that using QProcess is smth which is related to that but
when I coded the following:

```
 QProcess mysql;
    mysql.start("mysql", QStringList() << "-uroot -ppassword");

    if(!mysql.waitForStarted())
        qDebug() << "Not loaded...";

    mysql.write("show databases;");
    mysql.closeWriteChannel();

    if(!mysql.waitForFinished())
        qDebug() << "Haven't finished yet!";

    QByteArray result = mysql.readAll();
    QString str(result);
    qDebug("%s", qPrintable(str));
```

I'm receiving an empty string, could you help to check whether services started or not?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your problem. You have already in your code:

```
if(!mysql.waitForStarted())
        qDebug() << "Not loaded...";
```

This tells you clearly whether or not your mysql program started.

But if I may give you an advice, drop your idea using mysql via QProcess. This is fine to start the mysql server, but nothing more. Look into the Qt docs for QSqlDatabase. This allows you to connect to the server directly. Trying to open() your database with QSqlDatabase can give you by far more information, than the QProcess crutch you try to use.

Edit: Change your 'readAll' into 'readAllStandardError'. You will see something interesting.

Comment: Well, thank you. Actually, I've connected my server via QSqlDatabase. However, that won't work, till service for MySQl launched.

Comment: But do you launch a service with 'mysql'? 'mysql' is only a frontend to connect to the mysql server. To start the server you need to execute QProcess with 'mysqld'